# Executing handlers in any sequence

Tags: java

I have a list of list of classes/handlers: job1, job2, job3...
I want to execute them in the sequence I am getting from Redis. So ,  the sequence(list)  can be any sequence job1,job2,job3 or job3,job2,job1 .  Each job has its own implementation. I am trying to do the below: where I have written handler class, it will take the handler sequence and on executing it will execute in the requested sequence.

Is there any other way of doing this and how to get the same executed. Is my approach right?

```
    public class Main 
    {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException 
        {
        List handler  = new ArrayList<>();
        handler.add("job2");
        handler.add("job1");
        handler h = new handler(handler);
        h.execute();
        }
    }
```

Below is my handler class that will take the sequence and execute

```
     public class handler {
        List<handler> listhandler;



        enum jobs {
            job1 {
                @Override
                public void executeHandler() {
                    System.out.println("This is the job1");

                }
            },
            job2 {
                @Override
                public void executeHandler() {
                    System.out.println("This is the job2");

                }
            };

            public abstract void executeHandler();
        }

        public handler(List<handler> hand) {
            this.listhandler = hand;

        }

        public void execute() {

            for(handler ht : this.listhandler) {
                ht.getJobs().executeHandler();
            }


        }

        private jobs getJobs() {

            return null;
        }


     }
```

Comment: What is your exact problem? The only thing I see (aside from confusing code style and naming) is that you `Handler` constructor expects a list of `Handler`, but you try to give it a list of `String` - What type are the elements of `listHandler` supposed to be now? Shouldn't it be a list of `Jobs`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `handler` class expects a `List<handler>`, but you are adding Strings to the list. Instead, you should use `jobs` in both cases. The `jobs` enum itself looks okay.

```
public static class Handler {
   List<Job> listhandler;  // list of jobs

   public Handler(List<Job> hand) {
       this.listhandler = hand;
   }

   public void execute() {
       for(Job ht : this.listhandler) {
           ht.executeHandler();
       }
   }
} 

public static void main(String args[]) {
    List<Job> handler = new ArrayList<>();
    handler.add(Job.job2);  // add jobs, not job names
    handler.add(Job.job1);
    Handler h = new Handler(handler);
    h.execute();
}
```